# Generalization difference when using `nn.Sequential`?

Tags: pytorch

I have an autoencoder deep network, and I notice that when I use `nn.Sequential`, the generalization performance is better than when I don't use it (i.e. explicitly pass the inputs through layers). Has anyone else noticed this behavior, or can provide an explanation as to why this is? Does Pytorch handle regularization differently in a sequential block?

Here is a code snippet; I've attached the full code at the end for reference. I am toggling between using `nn.Sequential` and not using it with the variable `use_sequential`. I find that when I don't use the sequential module, my test accuracy is always worse than if I do use it.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, in_dim, use_sequential):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.use_sequential = use_sequential
        self.in_dim = in_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(in_dim),
                nn.Linear(in_dim, hidden_dim)
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(hidden_dim, in_dim),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(in_dim),
                nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim)
        )

    def encode(self, x):
        if self.use_sequential:
            x = self.encoder(x)
        else:
            x = self.lin1(x)
            x = self.batchnorm(x)
            x = self.lin2(x)
        return x

    def decode(self, x):
        if self.use_sequential:
            x = self.decoder(x)
        else:
            x = self.lin3(x)
            x = self.batchnorm(x)
            x = self.lin4(x)
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encode(x)
        x = self.decode(x)
        x = self.sig(x) # Sigmoid for BCELoss
        return x
```

Here's the output of the script. As you can see, the test accuracy/loss is worse as the models train, even though their train accuracy/loss remain similar (I initialize all weights myself, see full code at the end):

```
SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  0: loss=0.7185, acc=0.51
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  0: loss=0.7185, acc=0.51
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  0: loss=0.7240, acc=0.50080
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  0: loss=0.7240, acc=0.50080


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  1: loss=0.7192, acc=0.49
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  1: loss=0.7192, acc=0.49
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  1: loss=0.7226, acc=0.49920
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  1: loss=0.7221, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  2: loss=0.7207, acc=0.50
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  2: loss=0.7208, acc=0.50
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  2: loss=0.7183, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  2: loss=0.7186, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  3: loss=0.7032, acc=0.54
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  3: loss=0.7033, acc=0.54
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  3: loss=0.7104, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  3: loss=0.7153, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  4: loss=0.7002, acc=0.56
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  4: loss=0.7002, acc=0.56
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  4: loss=0.7006, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  4: loss=0.7119, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  5: loss=0.6906, acc=0.55
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  5: loss=0.6907, acc=0.55
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  5: loss=0.6903, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  5: loss=0.7088, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  6: loss=0.6807, acc=0.54
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  6: loss=0.6811, acc=0.54
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  6: loss=0.6815, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  6: loss=0.7058, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  7: loss=0.6698, acc=0.52
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  7: loss=0.6702, acc=0.52
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  7: loss=0.6729, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  7: loss=0.7033, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  8: loss=0.6710, acc=0.67
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  8: loss=0.6722, acc=0.60
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  8: loss=0.6643, acc=0.56120
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  8: loss=0.7014, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  9: loss=0.6642, acc=0.71
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch  9: loss=0.6659, acc=0.65
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  9: loss=0.6612, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch  9: loss=0.6999, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 10: loss=0.6593, acc=0.68
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 10: loss=0.6613, acc=0.68
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 10: loss=0.6570, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 10: loss=0.6988, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 11: loss=0.6522, acc=0.68
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 11: loss=0.6541, acc=0.68
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 11: loss=0.6540, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 11: loss=0.6978, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 12: loss=0.6651, acc=0.67
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 12: loss=0.6679, acc=0.67
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 12: loss=0.6511, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 12: loss=0.6971, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 13: loss=0.6617, acc=0.67
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 13: loss=0.6640, acc=0.67
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 13: loss=0.6494, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 13: loss=0.6964, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 14: loss=0.6506, acc=0.67
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 14: loss=0.6527, acc=0.67
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 14: loss=0.6470, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 14: loss=0.6961, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 15: loss=0.6479, acc=0.69
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 15: loss=0.6500, acc=0.69
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 15: loss=0.6453, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 15: loss=0.6954, acc=0.49920


SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 16: loss=0.6441, acc=0.70
NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch 16: loss=0.6461, acc=0.70
---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 16: loss=0.6445, acc=0.68860
---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch 16: loss=0.6950, acc=0.49920

...
```

I've found that the issue lies in the `BatchNorm1d` layer, because when I take it out of the model the issue disappears. Is there a difference between `BatchNorm1d` in a sequential block? Or have I made a mistake I am overlooking? Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the full code:

```
import torch
from torch.utils import data
from torch.optim import Adam
from tqdm import tqdm
class Dataset(data.Dataset):
    'Characterizes a dataset for PyTorch'
    def __init__(self, data, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the total number of samples'
        return len(self.labels)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generates one sample of data'
        # Load data and get label
        X = self.data[index]
        y = self.labels[index]
        return X, y

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim, in_dim, use_sequential):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.use_sequential = use_sequential
        self.in_dim = in_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(in_dim),
                nn.Linear(in_dim, hidden_dim)
                )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(hidden_dim, in_dim),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(in_dim),
                nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim)
                )


        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim)
        self.lin1.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        self.lin1.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

        self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(in_dim)
        self.batchnorm.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        self.batchnorm.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(in_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.lin2.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        self.lin2.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

        self.lin3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, in_dim)
        self.lin3.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        self.lin3.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

        self.lin4 = nn.Linear(in_dim, in_dim)
        self.lin4.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        self.lin4.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

    def encode(self, x):
        if self.use_sequential:
            x = self.encoder(x)
        else:
            x = self.lin1(x)
            x = self.batchnorm(x)
            x = self.lin2(x)
        return x

    def decode(self, x):
        if self.use_sequential:
            x = self.decoder(x)
        else:
            x = self.lin3(x)
            x = self.batchnorm(x)
            x = self.lin4(x)
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encode(x)
        x = self.decode(x)
        x = self.sig(x) # Sigmoid for BCELoss
        return x

def accuracy(preds, labels):
    acc2 = 1 - torch.sum(torch.abs(preds-labels)).item() / (list(preds.size())[0]*list(preds.size())[1])
    return acc2

def generate_data(block_size):
    train_data = torch.randint(2, (10000, block_size)).float()
    test_data = torch.randint(2, (2500, block_size)).float()

    train_labels = train_data
    test_labels = test_data
    return train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels

def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear or type(m) == nn.BatchNorm1d:
        m.weight.data.fill_(0.01)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)
    if type(m) == nn.PReLU:
        m.weight.data.fill_(0.01)

########################## Train code ####################
IN_DIM = 4
HIDDEN_DIM = 32
EPOCHS = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 256

# Generate data
train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = generate_data(IN_DIM)                                                   

# Data loading                                                                                                                                        
params = {'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,                                                                                                              
          'shuffle': True,                                                                                                                            
          'num_workers': 8}                                                                                                                
training_set = Dataset(train_data, train_labels)                                                                                                      
training_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, **params)                                                                                 

# Sequential and non-sequential models                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
model_seq = Net(hidden_dim=HIDDEN_DIM, in_dim=IN_DIM, use_sequential=True)   
model_non = Net(hidden_dim=HIDDEN_DIM, in_dim=IN_DIM, use_sequential=False)  
model_seq.apply(init_weights)
model_non.apply(init_weights)

loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()  

optimizer_seq = Adam(model_seq.parameters(), lr=0.001)
optimizer_non = Adam(model_non.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training  
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):                                                                                                                                                          
    model_seq.train()  
    model_non.train()
    for batch_idx, (batch, labels) in enumerate(training_loader):                            

        # Testing sequential model
        output_seq = model_seq(batch)                                                                                                                     
        loss_seq = loss_fn(output_seq, labels) 
        optimizer_seq.zero_grad()                                                                                                                     
        loss_seq.backward()                                                                                                                           
        optimizer_seq.step()     

        # Testing non-sequential model
        output_non = model_non(batch)                                                                                                                     
        loss_non = loss_fn(output_non, labels) 
        optimizer_non.zero_grad()                                                                                                                     
        loss_non.backward()                                                                                                                           
        optimizer_non.step()

        if batch_idx % (BATCH_SIZE-1) == 0:                                                                                                  
            pred_seq = torch.round(output_seq)                                                                                                            
            acc_seq = accuracy(pred_seq, labels)                                                                                                    
            print('SEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch %2d: loss=%.4f, acc=%.2f' % (epoch, loss_seq.item(), acc_seq))  

            pred_non = torch.round(output_non)                                                                                                            
            acc_non = accuracy(pred_non, labels)                                                                                                    
            print('NONSEQUENTIAL TRAIN, Epoch %2d: loss=%.4f, acc=%.2f' % (epoch, loss_non.item(), acc_non))          

            # Sequential Validation  
            model_seq.eval()
            val_output_seq = model_seq(test_data)
            val_loss_seq = loss_fn(val_output_seq, test_labels)
            val_pred_seq = torch.round(val_output_seq)
            val_acc_seq = accuracy(val_pred_seq, test_labels)
            print('---> SEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch %2d: loss=%.4f, acc=%.5f' % (epoch, val_loss_seq.item(), val_acc_seq))
            model_seq.train()

            # Nonsequential Validation
            model_non.eval()  
            val_output_non = model_non(test_data)
            val_loss_non = loss_fn(val_output_non, test_labels)
            val_pred_non = torch.round(val_output_non)
            val_acc_non = accuracy(val_pred_non, test_labels)
            print('---> NONSEQUENTIAL TEST: Epoch %2d: loss=%.4f, acc=%.5f' % (epoch, val_loss_non.item(), val_acc_non))
            model_non.train()

            print('\n')
```

Comment: What you compare this way: `nn.Sequentional` vs. `nn.ModuleList` or what?

Comment: How do you measure generalization in your case?

Comment: posting the code of the two approaches you are comparing would be helpful